# TypeError: must be str, not int in bubble sort

Tags: python, python-3.x, bubble-sort

I'm having this kind of error in my Python code in sorting algorithm (bubble sort)

> Traceback (most recent call last):     File "D:\CSC\PYTHON SAMPLE CODES\bubstepbystep.py", line 13, in 
>       nlist = nlist + i   TypeError: must be str, not int

I could not figure out what's happening inside. Please help me.

```
import time

nlist = input("Enter series of numbers: ")
swap = len(nlist)
qty = len(nlist)
print("Original:", nlist)


for x in range(qty - 1):
    for i in range(swap - 1):  #swap
    if nlist [i] > nlist [i+1]:
        temp = nlist [i]
        nlist = nlist + i
        nlist [i+1] = temp

        print("\nSwapping Index:", i,"and", i+1, "\n\rNew list:", nlist)
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        print("\nSwapping Index:", i,"and", i+1)
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Nothing to swap, skipping . . .")
        time.sleep(3)

swap -= 1
```

Comment: At what point do you convert the string returned from the `input(...)` into a list of numbers?

You seem to be trying to increment the whole list `nlist` while trying to swap values?

A swap in python can be done much more simply with the following pattern: `a, b = b, a`

Comment: Don't you want `nlist[i] = nlist[i+1]` there?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it also gives me an error

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are trying to add an int `i` to a string `nlist`.

Comment: @Gavin You mean, I must convert my strings into int?

Comment: Yes, you ask for a series of numbers, so if you expect the user to put in `1,3,2,7,4` you would convert that using `nlist = [int(num) for num in nlist.split(',')]` for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your input, I think: map it to proper integers and things look much better. Also, your swap code was not correct:

```
import time

nlist = list(map(int, input("Enter series of numbers: ").split()))
nlist 
swap = len(nlist)
qty = len(nlist)
print("Original:", nlist)

for x in range(qty - 1):
    for i in range(swap - 1):  #swap
        if nlist [i] > nlist [i+1]:
            temp = nlist [i]
            print(temp)
            nlist [i] = nlist [i+1]
            nlist [i+1] = temp

            print("\nSwapping Index:", i,"and", i+1, "\n\rNew list:", nlist)
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            print("\nSwapping Index:", i,"and", i+1)
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Nothing to swap, skipping . . .")
            time.sleep(3)

swap -= 1

print("Final:", nlist)
```

Comment: I assume here an input string like `5 6 7`

Comment: Thank you so much for figuring it out. God bless